# I am trying to solve the below mentioned problem statement

Tags: python-3.x, string

Problem statement:
1. If user provides a string as an input, we have to count the repeated occurrences and return how many times each element of string has occurred.
For eg.
input = '111223334'
returns output '31223314'
I am looking for a python solution.

Comment: What have you done to solve this? Show your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pythonic way would be to use [itertools.groupby()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

For example:

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = '111223334'
ans = ''.join(f'{len(list(v))}{k}' for k, v in groupby(inp)) # -> 31223314
```